# Converting R table to JSON string

Tags: json, r

I'm learning **R** and I'm doing a Predictive Analysis API using **R**, I'm using plumber to create a web API service. I need to retrieve the confusion Matrix of my Naive Bayes prediction result but unfortunately I could not find any method to convert the resulting object (R table object) to a JSON string.

One of my options is to manually create the JSON string, but I can't find the way of iterate through the table, including the row and column names.

This is an example of my table object:

```
          Active   Inactive   Hotlined   Suspended
Active       1        0          2           1
Inactive     0        2          0           0
Hotlined     3        0          3           2
Suspended    0        5          0           4
```

And the output that I need is similar to this:

```
[
   {column:'Active',row:'Active',value:1},
   {column:'Inactive',row:'Active',value:0},
   {column:'Hotlined',row:'Active',value:2},
   {column:'Suspended',row:'Active',value:1},
   .......... #The same for next rows
,]
```

Also, the table object can have less columns and/or less rows according the prediction result, I think I should mention this before
Any idea on how can I achieve this?

Comment: You could use a nested for loop to go through the table's rows and columns.

Comment: You need exactly this JSON structure?

Comment: @tluh i can loop through the table data, but i need the column and row name too and I can't achieve that

Comment: @MartinDabbelJuSmelter Yes, or something close to that... I need to re-build the resulting matrix and in fact, the matrix column and row qty changes according the prediction result

Comment: Does `toJSON(setNames(as.data.frame(tab),c("row","column","value")))` do it?

Comment: @thelatemail That completely works... thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer given by @thelatemail works and gives me the correct String

this is the answer

```
library(jsonlite)
toJSON(setNames(as.data.frame(tab),c("row","column","value")))
```

Thanks to all for the help

Answer (score 2):

Transform your data to long format and convert to json.
Example with tidyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(jsonlite)

df1 %>% 
  dplyr::add_rownames("row") %>% 
  tidyr::gather(column, value, -row) %>%
  arrange(row) %>% 
  select(column, row, value) %>% 
  toJSON(pretty = TRUE)

# [
#   {
#     "column": "Active",
#     "row": "Active",
#     "value": 1
#   },
#   {
#     "column": "Inactive",
#     "row": "Active",
#     "value": 0
#   },
#   {
#     "column": "Hotlined",
#     "row": "Active",
#     "value": 2
#   },
#
#   ...
```

Test input created with:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
          Active   Inactive   Hotlined   Suspended
  Active       1        0          2           1
  Inactive     0        2          0           0
  Hotlined     3        0          3           2
  Suspended    0        5          0           4
"
)
```

I think in your case you will have to convert your table object with `as.data.frame`.

Comment: Thank you so much,it's really close but is not working correctly... When i do
the as.data.frame convertion, it creates something like this:

var1        var2         Freq
Active    Active        0

For each row, i don't know if that's how it is supposed to be, And when i apply the method that you suggested the  resulting json is like this:
[ {
    "column": "Var1",
    "row": "1",
    "value": "Active"
  },....
And in some other cases it mixes the column, row and value information... The quantity of columns and rows may vary according the model

Comment: Can you `dput` a sample object?

Answer (score 0):

```
require(rjson)
Active   Inactive   Hotlined   Suspended
Active       1        0          2           1
Inactive     0        2          0           0
Hotlined     3        0          3           2
Suspended    0        5          0           4

d <- read.table(con <- file("clipboard"), header = T)

json <- toJSON(d)

d.json <- fromJSON(json)

data.frame(Active    = d.json$Active,
           Inactive  = d.json$Inactive,
           Hotlined  = d.json$Hotlined,
           Suspended = d.json$Suspended)
```

> ```
>   Active Inactive Hotlined Suspended
> 1      1        0        2         1
> 2      0        2        0         0
> 3      3        0        3         2
> 4      0        5        0         4
> ```